# Obtener un valor (element) de un datasource angular

Tags: typescript, angular12, mat-table

saludos. Favor agradecería su ayuda. Necesito saber como obtener un valor de una mat-table en angular 12 desde mi componente.ts, ya que no logro capturar desde el datasource mis registros de la tabla para luego poder hacer un ciclo for para validar si existe el registro o no, antes de insertar uno nuevo.

mi tabla en el html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="row" id="fila-tabla-cliente">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceMaquinaria" class="mat-elevation-z0">

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="codigo">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Código </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.maq_Codigo }} </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.maq_Nombre}} </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="valorMinimo">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Valor mínimo </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.maq_ValorMinArriendo}} </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="precio">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Precio </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.maq_ValorArriendo}} </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="tipoCobro">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tipo cobro </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.maq_TipoUltKmHm}} </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="acciones">
                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Acciones </mat-header-cell>
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn badge tbl-eliminar " (click)="openDialog('detalle')">
                                    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                </button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn badge tbl-eliminar " (click)="deleteMaquina()">
                                    <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                                </mat-cell>
                            </ng-container>
                            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsMaquinaria"></mat-header-row>
                            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsMaquinaria;"></mat-row>
                        </mat-table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

En mi componente.ts he intentando mostrar de varias formas mediante un console.log , pero siempre me da indefinido o error de ejecución. Aveces logro mostrar la lista de propiedades donde se ven los registros de la tabla, pero nunca logro mostrar unicamente un valor de una fila x por ejemplo.

```
showMaquina(){

    console.log("dataMaquina->",this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data);
       console.log("this.dataSourceMaquinaria.connect().value());
    
    
       this.dataSourceMaquinaria.connect().subscribe(dt=>{
         // dt.values
         console.log("this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data->",this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data.slice());
          
        });
    
       console.log("this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data->",this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data.values());
       console.log("this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data->",this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data[0].maq_Codigo);

}
```

Este es el error que me da generalmente con el ultimo log:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano.

Comment: pero tu datasource  no es un dato que vos mismo le suministras?....https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: No. el datasource es un objeto que contiene muchas propiedades y dentro vienen sus datos. con     console.log(this.dataSourceMaquinaria.data); me muestra cada registro de mi tabla. pero luego de eso no puedo obtener un campo especifico.

Comment: es lo que te quise decir es un objeto que lo Tenes como un dato del cual conoces la estructura compartí la estructura del dato que Tenes y cualquiera podrá ayudarte .Tambien te puede ayudar ` <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsMaquinaria;"  (click)="onRowClicked(row);$event.stopPropagation()">
      onRowClicked(row: any): void {
    console.log('row por ejemplo si columna define name', row.name)
  }`